# wrapping <div> in text middle right in css

Tags: html, css

how to wrap a

```
div
```

inside a text?

goal is to look like this..

```
text|text|text|text|text|text|text|text|text|
text|text|text|text|text|text|text|text|text|
         |text|text|text|text|text|text|text|
         |text|text|text|text|text|text|text|
         |text|text|text|text|text|text|text|
text|text|text|text|text|text|text|text|text|
text|text|text|text|text|text|text|text|text|
```

1. div is before text
2. text is paragraph
3. that is `<div></div><p></p>`

I have tried floating div and add margin-top but text does not wrap on top of div.
I have tried position:relative and position:absolute are overlapping (not text wrapping).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check this out! I am using [shape-outside](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/shape-outside/) property.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>This is the title</title>
 <style>
body {
  max-width: 500px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
div {
  -webkit-shape-outside: inset(100px 40px 40px 0px);
          shape-outside: inset(100px 40px 40px 0px);
  width: 142px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div></div>
 <p>
  |text|text|text|text|text|text|text|text|text|
  |text|text|text|text|text|text|text|text|text|
            |text|text|text|text|text|text|text|
            |text|text|text|text|text|text|text|
            |text|text|text|text|text|text|text|
  |text|text|text|text|text|text|text|text|text|
  |text|text|text|text|text|text|text|text|text|
 </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Reference: [shape-outside Property](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/shape-outside/)

Comment: this doesn't seems to be wrapping the text, you have put a background color instead

Comment: OP's concern is about wrapping the text with the div, not just printng the pattern

Comment: @bhansa If you check it closely, it is indeed pushing the p element to the right.

Answer (score 0):

By `shape-outside` Property.According to [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside)

> The shape-outside CSS property uses shape values to define the float area for a float and will cause inline content to wrap around the shape instead of the float's bounding box.

In your case you want to achieve rectangular shape, so there is a `inset()`function to do this

```
shape-outside: inset(50px 50px 50px 10px);
```

Here is the [pen](https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/b2da5018d8f20ac3a2ccc26edb724db6) by CSS-Tricks